# Adding parameters to URL, putting array in query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url, query-string

## Objective

I've built an interactive where people can choose six players to make their all-star team. When they click share to Twitter, my hope is to have a URL containing parameters of all six players something like `website.com/?playerName=picked?playerName=picked` so that people can share their teams

## Question

- What is the best way to append parameters to a URL?
- How do you put an array into a query string?

Answer (score 11):

You can use an array directly in a url, however you would need to serialize the array into a string. like this `player[]=one&player[]=two`

here is a little function to automate it.

when using url's you should always use `encodeURIComponent` to encode any non url friendly characters. The players are an array so we map over it and get a new array that has been encoded.

After that we simply need to join the array with `&`

```js
const players = [
  'player Name 1',
  'playerName2',
  'playerName3'
]

const parameterizeArray = (key, arr) => {
  arr = arr.map(encodeURIComponent)
  return '?'+key+'[]=' + arr.join('&'+key+'[]=')
}

console.log(parameterizeArray('player', players))
```

### edit

The only difference is the function declaration style, everything else is standard ES5

```js
function parameterizeArray(key, arr) {
  arr = arr.map(encodeURIComponent)
  return '?'+key+'[]=' + arr.join('&'+key+'[]=')
}
```

Comment: Do you mind also including a snippet w/o const and the newer ES2015 syntax

Answer (score 10):

Cleaner:

```
website.com/?players=player1,player2,player3,player4
```

Then split the query to get result:

```
var arrayResult = query.players.split(",")
```

Comment: this solution will require validation on the names not being able to have the "separated" values in this case, the commas.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on the built-in [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API to construct (and deconstruct) the querystring for you.

Using `append` to add new parameters to the end (using `set` will replace an existing parameter):

```js
const players = ["alice", "bob", "charlie"];

const params = new URLSearchParams();

players.forEach((player) => params.append("playerName", player));

console.log(params.toString());
```

Using `getAll` to retrieve an array of all values (using `get` will only get the first one):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams("playerName=alice&playerName=bob&playerName=charlie");

console.log(params.getAll("playerName"));
```

You can also get the URLSearchParams object [from a URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams):

```js
const url = new URL("https://website.com/?playerName=alice&playerName=bob&playerName=charlie");

const params = url.searchParams;

console.log(params.getAll("playerName"));
```